# Prove on Incenter and mid point.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles

Let the incircle (with center $I$) of $\triangle{ABC}$ touch the side $BC$ at $X$, and let $A'$ be the midpoint of this side. Then prove that line $A'I$ (extended) bisects $AX$.[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The incircle of $\triangle ABC$ has centre $I$ and touches $BC$ at $D$. Prove that $M,I,N$ are collinear](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4346587/the-incircle-of-triangle-abc-has-centre-i-and-touches-bc-at-d-prove-th)

Answer (score 2):

First denote the intersection of $A'I$ and $AX$ with $M$. Now let $IX$ intersect the incircle for a second time at $Y$. Then let $AY$ intersect $BC$ at $W$. It's well-known that $W$ is the tangent point of the excircle and $BC$ (you can check the proof of this lemma [here](http://yufeizhao.com/olympiad/geolemmas.pdf), Chapter $2$). Also it's well-known that $A'X = A'W$. Now consider $\triangle A'YX$, we have that $A'I \parallel AW$, since $A'I$ is a midline in the triangle. Now using this we have by Intercept Theorem:

$$\frac{AM}{AX} = \frac{A'W}{XW} = \frac 12$$

Therefore $M$ is a midpoint of $AX$.

Answer (score 1):

That is an almost trivial exercise in [barycentric coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarycentricCoordinates.html): you just have to check that
$$ \det\left(\frac{A+X}{2};I;A'\right) = 0 \tag{1} $$
given $I=\frac{aA+bB+cC}{a+b+c}$, $A'=\frac{B+C}{2}$ and $X=\frac{(p-c)B+(p-b)C}{a}$, but:

$$ (a+b+c) I = aA+bB+cC = a(X+A) + (p-a)(B+C).\tag{2}$$