# The incircle of $\triangle ABC$ has centre $I$ and touches $BC$ at $D$. Prove that $M,I,N$ are collinear

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

The incircle of $\triangle ABC$ has centre $I$ and touches $BC$ at $D$. Let the midpoints of $AD$ and $BC$ be $M$ and $N$ respectively. Prove that $M,I,N$ are collinear

My book proceeds like this-

> Let $NI$ meet $AD$ at $M'$. Join $A$ and $I$ and let $AI$ meet $BC$ at $L$. For $\triangle ADL$ with $NIM'$ as transversal, Menelaus gives-
> $$\frac {DN}{NL}\frac {LI}{IA}\frac {AM'}{M'D}=-1$$
> $$\frac {LI}{IA}=\frac {LC}{CA}=ab/(b+c)b$$
> And,
> $$DN/LN=\to\frac{BN-BD}{BN-BL}=\frac{a/2-(s-b)}{a/2-ac/(b+c)}\leftarrow=\frac{b+c}a$$

I tried but could not figure out how the highlighted portions were derived.

Please help.

[image]

Comment: Since you know how to typeset fractions, could you please do that properly with the quantities on the right-hand sides of the two equations?

Comment: Let $T$ be the antipode of $D$ in the incircle. Let $X$ be the reflection of $D$ wrt $N$ (which is the contact point of the $A$ exincircle with $BC$). It is fairly known that $ATX$ are colinear. It is fairly clear that $MIN$ is just the midline of $\triangle ADX$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first highlighted portion uses the [angle bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem) twice, using the fact that $I$ lies on the bisectors of the angles at $A$ and $C$.

The second highlighted section just applies known formulas for $BD$, $BN$ and $BL$ in terms of $a, b, c$, where $BL$ is obtained from the angle bisector theorem again and the formula for $BN$ is a simple consequence of the fact that the tangent points of the incircle divide the triangle sides into three pairs of equal lengths.

For an alternative proof using simple geometry, consider the excircle of $ABC$ opposite $A$ and the point $E$ where it touches $a$, as well as the point $F$ on the incircle opposite to $D$. Clearly scaling $M'IN$ around $D$ by factor $2$ yields $AFE$, and $AFE$ are collinear as seen by the scaling around $A$ mapping the incircle to the excircle.

[image]